# Git merger two branches or hand merge

Tags: git

We with my friend worked on one project. I worked with Git he does not. What I need to do? Create second branch push there his code? And than merge my branch and created?

Comment: Your question is not clear, provide more details. You both have different code? From now you plan both to use git?

Comment: Now we have different codes. Where some parts are similar. From now he should use git.

Comment: So your code already in git, you need to put his code to git also and merge both versions in some moment. Or you can develop in parallel if necessary

Comment: Yes i need to put his code to git also merge both version in some moment.

Comment: ok, so what is the question then?

Comment: I dont know ho to do this right. I am using source tree.

Comment: Start from introduction to git and if you will have any exact questions, post them. Now it is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend the following:

- copy your friend's sources onto your disk so that they are parallel to your versioned sources
- then, use a diff tool and do the merging manually (like in the bad old times)
- `git commit` the merged result
- then tell your mate that he should use git too in future or *he* will have to do the manual merging all the time